# How to restructure this code without duplicating too much code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop

```
class
{
public:
  void func(const int val, const bool flag)
  {
    if(flag)
    {
      while(!lower.empty() && val <= lower.top())
      {
        // do a bunch of stuff with lower
      }
    }
    else
    {
      while(!higher.empty() && val >= higher.top())
      {
        // do a bunch of stuff with higher, but it's the same stuff as would've done
        // for lower
      }
    }
  }
private:
  std::stack<int> lower;
  std::stack<int> higher;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a better way to write the clauses because currently, I have a lot of duplicate code in both. The only difference is one clause operates on `lower` and the other on `higher` and the `<=` in the first clause is changed to `>= higher` in the second one.

I could wrap the clause in a helper function and call it in each clause (and pass in the `lower` and `higher` as an argument), e.g.,

```
class
{
public:
  void func(const int val, const bool flag)
  {
    if(flag)
    {
      helper(lower, comparer);
    }
    else
    {
      helper(lower, comparer);
    }
  }

  void helper(std::stack<int> &st)
  {
    // do a bunch of stuff with st
  }
  
private:
  std::stack<int> lower;
  std::stack<int> higher;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a good idea and if it is, I'm not sure how to get around the `>=` vs. `<=`. I'm hoping for suggestions on my design!

Comment: Extract a method that takes the stack?

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you expand on what that means? Is it like the helper function I described in the second snippet?

Comment: This should be fine; in fact it's done quite often in the standard libary. Usually you make the parameter a template parameter though. Not sure if this was the plan, since the helper function takes only a single parameter currently. `template<typename ComparerType> void Helper(std::stack<int>& st, int val, ComparerType compare) { while(!st.empty() && compare(val, st.top()) { ... } }` `Helper(lower, val, [](int a, int b) { return a <= b; });`

Comment: @fabian instead of lambdas, you can use [`std::less_equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_equal) and [`std::greater_equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_equal), eg: `Helper(lower, val, std::less_equal{});` `Helper(higher, val, std::greater_equal{});`

Comment: @fabian Ah I see. So the template parameter here is purely for signaling to the function which comparer to use?

Comment: @fabian Also I think the formatting is a bit off but is the lambda function an argument for the comparer function? I copy and pasted it and I think there's some stuff missing

Comment: @westcoaststudent no, the lambda IS the comparer function. That is the whole point of the `compare` parameter, it lets the caller specify a comparer for the helper to call. It could be a lambda, a free function, a functor, etc. There is nothing missing in what fabian showed, it should be working, provided you are compiling for C++11 or higher.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah I see now. The `Helper(lower, val, [](int a, int b) { return a <= b; })` part in that comment is actually to show how the function is called.

Comment: What if instead of a `helper` function, I use the `flag` variable to create another variable that's a pointer or reference to one of the two stacks and also create a comparer? e.g., ```if(flag) {auto &ref = lower; auto comparer = std::less_equal{}} else {auto &ref = higher; auto_comparer = std::greater_equal{}}```

Comment: @westcoaststudent the template parameter is there to impose as little restrictions on the comparer as possible. You could pass an object with an `operator()` with return type convertible to bool and 2 parameters with types that can be assigned from `int`; the lambda is such an object; it's just a bit inconvenient to name it's type, but this isn't an issue, since the compiler automatically derives the template parameter. You could alternatively pass a function pointer with the same signature.

Comment: hmmm actually I think the reference idea won't work because it's going to go out of scope after I get out of the if-else statement and I can't define the reference before the if statement either since I can't reassign it, so it'd have to be a pointer

Comment: @westcoaststudent that could work, but not the way you have shown it, it would need to be more like this instead: `stack<int> *st; bool (*comparer)(int, int); if (flag) { st = &lower; comparer = [](int a, int b){ return a <= b; }; } else { st = &higher; comparer = [](int a, int b){ return a >= b; }; } while (!st->empty() && comparer(val, st->top())) { ... }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You could still use `greater_equal` or `less_equal` instead of the lambda right?

Comment: Also another thing is in this case I guess I could just swap the order of arguments and not define a separate comparer function for each scenario.

Comment: @westcoaststudent in this last case, no, using `std::less_equal`/`std::greater_equal` would actually not work without a template, since they don't have a common ancestor to declare the `comparer` variable as. That is why I went back to using lambdas instead, since *non-capturing* lambdas can decay into function pointers. Actually, you might be able to do something with `std::function`, but that would just be more overhead than you really need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```cpp
class
{
public:
  void func(const int val, const bool flag)
  {
    std::stack<int> *st;
    bool (*compare)(int, int);

    if (flag)
    {
      st = &lower;
      compare = [](int a, int b){ return a <= b; };
    }
    else
    {
      st = &higher;
      compare = [](int a, int b){ return a >= b; };
    }

    while (!st->empty() && compare(val, st->top()))
    {
      // do a bunch of stuff with *st
    }
  }

private:
  std::stack<int> lower;
  std::stack<int> higher;
}
```

Alternatively, using a helper would certainly work, too:

```cpp
class
{
public:
  void func(const int val, const bool flag)
  {
    if (flag)
      func_helper(lower, val, std::less_equal{});
    else
      func_helper(higher, val, std::greater_equal{});
  }

private:
  std::stack<int> lower;
  std::stack<int> higher;

  template<typename Comparer>
  void func_helper(stack<int> &st, const int val, Comparer compare)
  {
    while (!st.empty() && compare(val, st.top()))
    {
      // do a bunch of stuff with st
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
class
{
public:
  void func(const int val, const bool flag)
  {
    int sign = 1;
    std::stack<int>* higher_or_lower = &higher; 
    if(flag)
    {
      higher_or_lower = &lower;
      sign = -1;
    }

    while(!higher_or_lower->empty() && sign*val >= sign*higher_or_lower->top())
    {
      // do a bunch of stuff with higher_or_lower
    }
  }
  
private:
  std::stack<int> lower;
  std::stack<int> higher;
}
```

The `higher_or_lower` covers both stacks and the `sign` takes care of less than vs. greater than.

Comment: The sign idea is interesting, but I think maybe it's not as clear to read for someone? Certainly shorter though!

Answer (score 0):

Or a bit more compact:

```
class C
{
public:
    void func(const int val, const bool flag)
    {
        const std::stack<int>* st[] = {&lower, &higher};
        bool (*compare[])(int, int) = { [](int a, int b) { return a <= b; } ,  [](int a, int b) { return a >= b; } };

        while (!st[flag]->empty() && compare[flag](val, st[flag]->top()))
        {
            // do a bunch of stuff with *st
        }
    }

private:
    std::stack<int> lower;
    std::stack<int> higher;
};
```